# Declaring a const BYTE * in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, certificate

I am currently trying to make a call to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376035%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function call. Here's the declaration:

```
const void* WINAPI CertCreateContext(
  __in      DWORD dwContextType,
  __in      DWORD dwEncodingType,
  __in      const BYTE *pbEncoded,
  __in      DWORD cbEncoded,
  __in      DWORD dwFlags,
  __in_opt  PCERT_CREATE_CONTEXT_PARA pCreatePara
);
```

As you can see, the third input param calls for a const BYTE * which represents the encoded certificate you are trying to create. How do I define such a variable in c++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to. The function parameter is a pointer to a const BYTE, which means the function  will not change the byte it points to.  A simple example:

```
void f( const BYTE * p ) {
    // stuff
}

BYTE b = 42;
BYTE a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

f( & b );
f( a );
```

You will of course need to #include the header that declares the type BYTE.

Comment: @GMan I know, which is why they are the only ones I ask about, in the forlorn hope the downvoter might explain themselves.

Comment: Agreed- the answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Neil: perhaps an old-school Microsoft zealot wanted the answer in Hungarian to match the question. Or maybe it was punishment for missing a `;`. Either way, +1 for being right.

Comment: @Mike I normally compile real code before I  post it, but for questions like this rely on my code writing prowess - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to declare a `BYTE*`, the compiler will automatically cast's non-`const`s to `const`s.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376035%28VS.85%29.aspx):

*pbEncoded is a pointer to a buffer that contains the existing encoded context content to be copied.*

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a regular pointer to BYTE.  The `const` there indicates that the pointed-to object will not be modified inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, Neil. I meant to say the *object being pointed to* will not be modified.  The pointer itself certainly can't be modified when passed by value, `const` or otherwise.  Fixed